# Displaying data from an Oracle Table through SQL Query

Tags: oracle-xe

I am not able to attach a screenshot because I am a new user here.
By the way, I am trying to view data from a table through SQL.
I have **created the table** using the following command:-

```
CREATE TABLE  N2 
   (    BOOK_ID VARCHAR2(6) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    BOOK_NAME VARCHAR2(150) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    AUTHOR_ID CHAR(6), 
    PUBLICATION_ID CHAR(6), 
    MAJOR_SUB_ID CHAR(6), 
    MINOR_SUB_ID CHAR(6)
   )
```

But the problem is that **no record is displayed** for the query:-

```
Select * from N2 where book_id='B0001';
```

though it can be seen that there is a record having book_id=B0001
This problem is removed if I use char type for book_id column or I write

```
Select * from N2 where book_id like 'B0001%';
```

One more thing is that this problem doesn't occur with other columns of varchar2 data type.

Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Classic : you probably have a trailing space of hidden character (line feed) at the end of your data...

you could achieve the same result with :

```
Select * from N2 where trim(book_id)='B0001';
```

but it would be better to clean up your data as I presume this character shouldn't be in your ID field

Comment: Thanks for your help :)
you are right, the problem is indeed with trailing spaces but that's not due to line feed.
Actually, I figured out the problem later. The problem was that the data in the table had been copied from another table in which the column book_id was of char type and as char type values are right padded with spaces upto the vacant places so when the data was copied the spaces were also copied alongwith the book_id